# How to do a SQL insert inside of varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, insert, varchar

How I can do a insert of sql syntax inside of varchar in mysql?

example:

```
INSERT INTO vartemp (SQLSyntax)
VALUES ('UPDATE RegExample SET Field1 = 'abc', Field2 = 123 WHERE whereCond1 = 'abc'')
```

where:

Vartemp is my table of SQL Syntax.

RegExample is a example of table.

Comment: u want to store strin containing sql query?

Comment: i think that it not a good practice...

Comment: It's a just test to test a windows service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO vartemp (SQLSyntax)
    VALUES ('UPDATE RegExample SET Field1 = ''abc'', Field2 = 123 WHERE whereCond1 = ''abc''')
```

If so, all you need to do is properly escape the embedded single quotes in the string.  The escape method for a single quote is two single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

change `'` to  double `''`